# Use #selector instead of explicitly constructing a Selector

Tags: xcode, swift

In the following snippet, what is the reason why Xcode recommend "Use #selector instead of explicitly constructing a Selector"?

```
// addButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, 
//             target: self, action: #selector(FoldersMaintenanceVC.addButtonPressed))
addButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, 
            target: self, action: Selector("addButtonPressed"))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton

func addButtonPressed()
{
    myNslogSys2(self, funcName:#function)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It recommends that you use the [Swift 2.2 new #selector](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md) because it is more type-safe since you cannot make a selector reference to a non-existing method whereas with Selector(String), you could reference a non-existing one.

Comment: There is a flaw in this though.    If I supply a wrong class that has an existing method but my intended target class - self, etc. does not have this existing method, it will crash at run time.

Comment: What can I do if i want to do something like this:   if responder!.respondsToSelector(Selector("aMethod:")) == true{ ...}

Comment: @KyleKIM If aMethod comes from a class or a protocol and is not optional, probably something like `if let responder = responder as? Protocol { responder.aMethod(value) }` Or otherwise `if responder!.respondToSelector(#selector(Protocol.aMethod(_:)) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Using `#selector` is now the correct way in Swift to reference a selector. Use of the struct `Selector` and string literals for selectors, such as `"mySel:"` have been deprecated.

The new `#selector` is now type safe and allows for compiler checking and autocompletion of the selector that you're passing in. This fixes the very common mistake of a spelling mistake in your selector (in the case of string literals)

Answer (score 1):

It happens cause now construction of Selector from string literals deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3.0

> With the introduction of the #selector syntax, we should deprecate the
>   use of string literals to form selectors. Ideally, we could perform
>   the deprecation in Swift 2.2 and remove the syntax entirely from Swift
>   3.

You can read more details about this change here https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md